# Check if user is member of dbo role in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a T-SQL statement to check if a user is member of a database role in SQL Server. Specifically I need to know if the user is member of the dbo role, because then I don't have to grant additional authority to that user.

If I try to add additional authority when the user is dbo it fails, and my script fails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing: (edit based on comment)

```
DECLARE @ISSYSADMIN INT
SET @ISSYSADMIN = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                   FROM sys.syslogins 
                   WHERE sysadmin = 1 AND loginname = '$(ContentAccount)')
```

The $(ContentAccount) is of course a parametrization which has the user domain and name!

This solves my problem because when we deploy a new database we are assigning permissions manually. But in development environments where the user we try to add already is sysadmin they fail. So if we check for sysadmin membership that is enough to cover the dev server scenario.

Then I do this to check membership:

```
IF (@ISSYSADMIN = 0)
BEGIN
  -- Add authority
END
```

Comment: If you are wanting to just know if the user is a member of sysadmin a much simpler query: "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sys.syslogins WHERE sysadmin = 1 AND loginname = 'Domain\MyUser'"

Comment: @ShawnMelton. That was much nicer, thanks! The reason for checking sysadmin was that IS_ROLEMEMBER with user principal didn't work for me and I needed a solution asap. Thought I needed to check dbo, but sysadmin is good enough to cover my scenario.

Answer (score 23):

[`IS_ROLEMEMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677633.aspx)?

```
IF IS_ROLEMEMBER ('db_owner') = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Is owner'
END
```

Or, if querying for a different user:

```
IF IS_ROLEMEMBER ('db_owner','other user') = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Is owner'
END
```

Comment: I think this is the answer, with the exception that when using the option with 'other user' I do not get the expected results. The user domain\qwerty is a sysadmin and when checking his user mappings for the database it say db_owner. But when calling the IS_ROLEMEMBER it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a simple solution for checking whether windows accounts have membership via AD security group membership?  Or would I have to list all the groups an account's a member of (recursively) and check each until I found a match?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example from the MSDN page on the [`IS_MEMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186271.aspx) function:

```
-- Test membership in db_owner and print appropriate message.
IF IS_MEMBER ('db_owner') = 1
   PRINT 'Current user is a member of the db_owner role'
ELSE IF IS_MEMBER ('db_owner') = 0
   PRINT 'Current user is NOT a member of the db_owner role'
ELSE IF IS_MEMBER ('db_owner') IS NULL
   PRINT 'ERROR: Invalid group / role specified'
```

Answer (score 2):

`IS_SRVROLEMEMBER` is the function you want.

```
IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin','myuser') = 1 PRINT 'Is SysAdmin'

IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('serveradmin','myuser') = 1 PRINT 'Is ServerAdmin'
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176015.aspx)