# SQL server login not attaching with user

Tags: sql, authentication

In my sql database i am trying to run procedure sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix','userx'  to fix orphaned user with login but it says you do not have permission to perform this action.

When i try to grant permission to user (using grant all on sp_change_users_login to 'userx' )it says cannot give permission to dbo owner or sys admin

i have imported this database with new name to make copy of it.

When i log in it shows default database as master.
I run script use dbx to connect to particular database.

Can someone help please.

Edit - I remember i have used sp_change_users_login 'update_one' 'user','login' successfully earlier.

Comment: "Requires membership in the db_owner fixed database role. **Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can specify the Auto_Fix option.**" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 - With that said, the user/login who is performing the action must have the membership, not the user you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it is hard to make any suggestions, other than the things listed in books online:

> **Remarks**
>
> Use sp_change_users_login to link a database user in the current database with a SQL Server login. If the login for a user has changed, use sp_change_users_login to link the user to the new login without losing user permissions. The new login cannot be sa, and the user cannot be dbo, guest, or an INFORMATION_SCHEMA user.
>
> sp_change_users_login cannot be used to map database users to Windows-level principals, certificates, or asymmetric keys.
>
> sp_change_users_login cannot be used with a SQL Server login created from a Windows principal or with a user created by using CREATE USER WITHOUT LOGIN.
>
> sp_change_users_login cannot be executed within a user-defined transaction.
>
> **Permissions**
>
> Requires membership in the db_owner fixed database role. **Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can specify the Auto_Fix option.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql

The bold part means, that when you are part of the db_owner database role in the database, but you are not sysadmin on the server, you can use

```
sp_change_users_login 'update_one','user','login'
```

but you cannot use

```
sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix','user'
```

Comment: Hi @peter whilst trying to give permission as -> use myDatabase
grant all on database::myDatabase to user1 it says Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
This means user1 is dbo so sp_change_users_login must work but its not working. shows you do not have permission. Moreover I tried to simply create one new login and one new user attached to it but its again saying you do not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: That does not mean, it is dbo. The list contains way more options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141507/check-if-user-is-member-of-dbo-role-in-sql-server for more info on this. Being DBO does not mean, you can do `auto_fix`, because it potentially creates a login for the user, which requires `sysadmin` on server level. The user/login you are connected needs to be dbo/sysadmin and not the user you are trying to change. `LOGIN` and `Database USER` are two different things. `sysadmin` and `dbo` are two different things. `@Pred` and `@peter` are two different things too :)

Comment: I am sorry @Pred :) could see this now only.